# Get icon from customised listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I created a custom listview for installed apps. The listview contains icon and text. Now my problem is how to get/retrieve the `BitmapDrawable` icon from the customised listview when `onListItemClick`?

The icons in the custom listview is from:

`static ArrayList<BitmapDrawable> Iconlist= new ArrayList<BitmapDrawable>();`.

Inside `onListItemClick` I used:

`SelectedIcon=(BitmapDrawable) Iconlist.get(position);`

to get the icon, but its not working.

Please help me.

Comment: What is being set in SelectedIcon? Icon at wrong index or you are getting some sort of exception?

Comment: SelectedIicon is initialized as `static BitmapDrawable SelectedIcon;` and the program runs smoothly but getting icon is different from the clicked one.

Comment: How are you binding list which contains icon and text to listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rakesh Bhalani says, you should use the view returned by `onListItemClick` as argument, casting the view for an ImageView:

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(id_of_your_icon);`

then extract the drawable from the ImageView, casting as BitmapDrawable:

`BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();`

Answer (score 1):

In `onItemClick` listener of `ListView` you will get clicked '`view`' as an argument, you should use `view.findViewById(id_of_your_icon)` to get the icon.

Comment: but it returns a view object. Can i convert it into BitmapDrawable object?